# Syntax highlighting code with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, syntax-highlighting

What Javascript libraries can you recommend for syntax highlighting <code> blocks in HTML?

(One suggestion per answer please).

Comment: http://shjs.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 104, accepted):

StackOverflow uses the [Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) library.

Comment: I second this. Google Code uses it for their own repo highlighting (since they wrote it) and automatically detects the language.

Comment: Surely using one which "automatically" detects the language simply puts more weight on the client's machine/browser...

Comment: You can give the language to Prettify if you know it, it will improve the performance. This is just not used in StackOverflow due to the large language audience.

Comment: Just added this to my web site, and it's great and so simple to use!

Comment: @Vincent: it improves more than just performance ;-)

Comment: @SamB: feel free to edit the answer to add more information. If you don't have enough reputation, you can add a comment and someone will add it to the answer

Comment: by any chance this works on Drupal 7 ? i will try this later tonight and let you all know, but prior to that if anyone knows any potholes do let me know

Comment: For me works just fine. Really easy to implement into the HTML and the result is astonishing. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Is it possible to comment code like Git-hub does?

Comment: This is now archived.

Answer (score 44):

I recently developed one called rainbow.

The main design goal was to make the core library really small and make it really easy for developers to extend.

See http://rainbowco.de.

Comment: I just ran across Rainbow today — it looks to me like it can discriminate more finely than Prettify (like for instance, being able to tell when `rdf:type` is used as an element and when it's an attribute).

Comment: This needs to go up to the top, Craig. I tried all of the other solutions and only Rainbow handled Python correctly and had *readable* theme stylesheets. Amazing plugin!

Answer (score 26):

[SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) is available as a [GitHub project](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter).

Answer (score 16):

What about [Prism](http://prismjs.com/) by Lea Verou.

From her [blog post](http://lea.verou.me/2012/07/introducing-prism-an-awesome-new-syntax-highlighter/) announcement in June (2012):

> - It’s tiny. The core is only 1.5KB minified & gzipped.
> - It’s incredibly extensible. Not only it’s easy to add new languages (that’s a given with every syntax highlighter these days), but also to
>     extend existing ones.
> - It supports parallelism through Web Workers, for better performance in certain cases.
> - It doesn’t force you to use any Prism-specific markup, not even a Prism-specific class name, only standard markup you should be using
>     anyway. So, you can just try it for a while, remove it if you don’t
>     like it and leave no traces behind.

Comment: This ended up being the best option of all the answers for me because of the ease of adding new language definitions.

Answer (score 15):

[jQuery Syntax Highlighter](https://github.com/balupton/jquery-syntaxhighlighter) is a new one based on [Google's Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) - a really really really popular plain javascript syntax highlighter.

It supports such things as `code` and `pre` blocks, able to use classnames like `language-javascript` to indicate we want it to highlight, as well as wordwrap. You can copy and paste code by selecting it normally instead of having to open a raw view like many others. It can be further customised by using the HTML5 data attribute `data-sh` or via specifying options at initialisation. A great stable choice which is updated regularly.

Comment: The author actually says it's based on Google's Prettify, not SyntaxHighlighter. Looks just like SyntaxHighlighter 3, though, but seems to require a lot less work to set up. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 5):

How about:

[syntaxhighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/)

[highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)

[JSHighlighter](http://www.devpro.it/jshighlighter/)

Comment: A simply Google search would also give me that list--but which one you prefer and why?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using jQuery there's Chilli:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-chili-js/

All you have to do is include the jquery-chili.js and recipes.js, and do the highlight with

```
$("code").chili();
```

It should figure out the language by itself.

Comment: The links to examples on that page all lead to an expired domain full of ads so it's a little bit difficult to get an idea of what this highlighter looks like.

Answer (score 5):

I'm very happy with **[SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/)**. It supports a bevy of languages and seems pretty fast and accurate.

Here's an example where I use it on **[my blog](http://andrew.hedges.name/blog/2008/05/13/widget-javascript-the-un-series-part-0)**. I'm using my own custom CSS file that simulates **[Coda's](http://panic.com/coda/)** syntax highlighting. Email me if you'd like to use it.

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery.Syntax](http://www.oriontransfer.co.nz/software/jquery-syntax) is an extremely fast and lightweight syntax highlighter. It has dynamic loading of syntax source files and integrates cleanly using CSS or modelines.

It was developed specifically to fill a gap - that is: a fast, clean, client-side syntax parser.

Comment: unfortunately it thought a standard FpML message to be SPAM :)

Comment: @ehosca, are you able to give me some clarification on problem you are having?

Comment: when i paste the xml in http://goo.gl/PPcDx to http://goo.gl/qSqm9 it says Invalid content, appears to be spam. hope this helps.

Comment: You need to include some line breaks in the text, otherwise it looks like link spam. I can't remember the exact formulae I used, but I think if you have more than one URL per line the text is considered spam - this is because heaps of bots were spamming the system (http://www.syntax-highlighing.com).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not being argumentative but just thought it worth mentioning that if you're using a CMS or blog platform then using a backend highlighter is better for obvious reasons — Have a look at [Geshi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)(http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) if you're interested. Actually you could set up your server to parse HTML content through a backend technology — so there is no need for the JS highlighters at all. (The only functionality they add is the ability to print/copy[using swf].)

Comment: It's not obvious to me. Why is using a backend highlighter better?

Comment: Yeah, I, too, would *really* love to know what is "obvious" about preferring to send a larger response to the client...

Comment: I prefer the syntax highlighting to still be present on devices that don't have JS enabled. Additionally, client-side highlighters have runtime costs that can be quite hefty if you've got lots of code to highlight. That said, it depends on your specific use-case :)

Comment: What devices don't have JS enabled?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for syntax highlighting in an in-browser editor, try [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net).

Answer (score 2):

[SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/)

Answer (score 2):

[This article at the Web Resources Depot](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/11-syntax-highlighters-to-beautify-code-presentation/) lists a bunch of options for highlighting code, some of which use Javascript. It was published on 4th May 2009.