# Looking for customizable syntax highlighting in the browser

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a customizable JavaScript script which dynamically highlights code in a block like

<code class="someclass">source code...</code>

It needs to be customizable because the source code is in a quite esoteric programming language (Mozart/Oz). Ideally, I'd just edit some regexes to make it work.

I need dynamic highlighting because it should work in the github wiki which escapes all HTML code within a pre tag.

My Google fu has forsaken me so far...

Comment: IMHO, this is a duplicate <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160694/syntax-highlighting-code-with-javascript>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) might be what you're looking for. It supports custom languages, as well.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Syntax Highlighter](http://www.balupton.com/projects/jquery-syntaxhighlighter/) is a new one based on version 3 of [Alex Gorbatchev's Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) - a really really really popular plain javascript syntax highlighter.

It supports such things as `code` and `pre` blocks, able to use classnames like `language-javascript` to indicate we want it to highlight, as well as wordwrap. You can copy and paste code by selecting it normally instead of having to open a raw view like many others. It can be further customised by using the HTML5 data attribute `data-sh` or via specifying options at initialisation. A great stable choice which is updated regularly.