# Is it possible to use SO's script that colorizes code in questions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax highlighting code with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160694/syntax-highlighting-code-with-javascript)

I have noticed that Stack Overflow uses some sort of script to colorize any code posted in questions and answers to try and mimic what it would look like in an IDE as much as possible. Is this script available for us to use? Where can I find it?

Alternatives to SO's script are welcome.

**Implementation**

Wow, I got prettify working in under 15 minutes without a problem. Thanks guys!
[Check out](http://www.CodeTunnel.com) my implementation of it if you care.

Comment: It's called a **syntax highlighter**.

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry for the duplicate. Did not include the word "syntax" in my searches for questions like this or I probably would have found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a Syntax Highlighter.

I've used this one in the past: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few js libraries around, have a look at http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/