# How to Auto-Colorize Codes Like HTML Editors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Blog, I want to Auto-Colorize its codes when I post something in HTML/CSS/Javascript/Jquery etc.. Just like Stackoverflow
I know I'm a worst explainer, let me try it..
like this, its automatically colorize the script..

```
<style type='text/css'>
img.opacity {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
img.opacity:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
</style>
```

I want this feature on my Blog, can you help me please??
This is my Blog: http://kownleg.blogspot.com/

Comment: Google "javascript code colorization plugins". There are many available solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax highlighting code with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160694/syntax-highlighting-code-with-javascript)

Comment: to make this a better question, you would need to narrow down the options a bit by showing what you tried, and explaining what stack you're running (in this case it's maybe possible to figure out via blogspot url, but you don't want to leave that as an exercise for the reader in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to parse the text, and based on keywords, syntax etc colour your code using css.

An example of this would be JavaToHTML which uses Java to convert a Java file to HTML.  It may be worth reading up on this and seeing how it works.

Comment: can you pls give me the link where I can easily find it??

Comment: http://www.java2html.com/  There are also many implementations in javascript/php etc

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [CodeMirror](http://www.codemirror.net/). It works amazingly well and I'm pretty sure Stack Overflow uses it.

**EDIT:** I was wrong. Stack Overflow [uses something else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network). Anyway, CodeMirror is extremely popular and you should have a look at it.