# way to achieve syntax highlighting

Tags: java, xhtml, syntax-highlighting

I am in need to achieve syntax highlighter for a web page., but I have no experience(either Idea) on it. Please guide me to make some good work on it.

Most of my web page may include Java codings and I will design my web page by using JSf with primefaces.

Guide me by any links or any thoughts to proceed with that work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Software recommendation questions aren't considered appropriate for SO. Syntax highlighting is usually done with javascript after a page is loaded to let you just emit a simple `<code>` in your server-side code, so search for "javascript syntax highlighting"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax highlighting code with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160694/syntax-highlighting-code-with-javascript)

Comment: Note that this is completely unrelated to JSF. All you need to do is to let JSF print the desired sourcecode blocks inside HTML `<pre><code>` tags. StackOverflow and OmniFaces showcase sites use Prettify. PrimeFaces and RichFaces showcase sites use Syntaxhighlighter.

Comment: Yes BalusC. I just intended to express the technology that I am using. So only I noted JSF here. Now I understood the things. Thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this javascript highlighter: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/. Used in WordPress, works great.