# Is there a Javascript Javascript Beautifier (color markup)

Tags: javascript, html, css, markup

I'd like to display a block of JavaScript code on my website, and have it marked up in such a way that the variables, reserved words, ect, are color coded.  I've checked several site for their CSS and JavaScript which is assigning classes and styles to the text, but so far, all of their methods have been sufficiently obfuscated such that I can't utilize their methods.  I found and easily implemented a FANTASTIC format tool in JS-Beautify, but it doesn't color code.  I saw that he is using code-mirror on his web interface, but was unable to determine how to implement it on my own.  Unfortunately, doing an internet search for this isn't helping a lot because when you combine search terms Javascript, code, CSS, format, markup, stylsheet, etc.  all kinds of results appear, but none of what I want.

Does anyone know where I can find either a CSS for Javascript code, or a combo of JS & CSS to apply classes/styles to color code my code?
Thanks!

Comment: Search for "JavaScript syntax highlighting"

Comment: There are plenty. Here's [prism](http://prismjs.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax highlighting code with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160694/syntax-highlighting-code-with-javascript)

Comment: Flagged as **too broad:** *There are either too many possible answers[...].*

Comment: Thanks all, this was actually very helpful.  I just wasn't searching the proper terms.

Comment: I chose to use Craig Campbell's "Rainbow."  [here](http://travishoward.net/euler/displayCode.php?problemNumber=8) you can see how I implemented it.